# How do I write an excel macro that will calculate the cumulative distance between points

Tags: excel, pythagorean, vba

I am trying to write an Excel macro that will calculate the cumulative distance between points based on their x and y coordinates. Here is an example of my current worksheet set-up:

```
Point #       Code     x coordinate    y coordinate   Cumulative distance between points

 1            1           39.4             99.8                       0
 2            1           42.5             104.5                      ?
 3            1           43.0             105.8                      ?   
 4            2           34.0             150.5                      ?
 5            3           38.9             145.9                      ?
 6            1           46.2             103.4                      ?
 7            1           48.5             105.3                      ?
 8            4           67.6             98.5                       ?
 9            1           50.3             103.2                      ?
```

I need the "cumulative distance between points" column to calculate the distance between the the point and previous point using Pythagorean formula `=SQRT(((D2-D1)^2)+((C2-C1)^2))))`. For each subsequent value in the "cumulative distance between points" column the value must calculate the distance between the previous points and add a running total of all distances calculated.

Here's the kicker. I only want the distance between the two points to be calculated if they both have a code of "1". If you look at my example you can see I have codes with values between 1-4.

In the above example, therefore, I would want to calculative the distance between point # 2 and 1. Next, I would calculate the distance between point # 3 and 2, and add it to the value obtained from the previous cell in the column (=distance between point # 2 and 1). Next I would skip points 4 and 5 as they do not have codes = "1". The next calculation would be between point # 6 and 3, as they both have codes = "1". Point 8 would be skipped as the code = "4". Then calculate the distance between point # 9 and 7. Keep in mind that every time a value is calculated in the "cumulative distance between points" column it must be a cumulative value that adds all the previous values to it.

So to wrap it up, I need the following:

-In the "cumulative distance between points" column calculate the distance between points (using x, y coordinates) when both codes = 1.
-add the previous cumulative distances to the cell value to get a running total of distance.

I hope that is clear, if not I can fill in any blanks that are confusing.

Comment: +1: Your question is clear and well-posed

Answer (score 0):

You could do this on the worksheet albeit with a few extra columns.

1) Create two new columns "copied x" and "copied y". Put formulas in these columns that, if the code on a row is 1, copies the x and y columns *on that row*. For any other code, copy the **copied** x and y values from the *previous* row. Use the Excel `IF` function to do this.

2) Calculate the cumulative pythagorean differences on all the successive "copied x" and "copied y". It will add a zero contribution for any row with a code other than 1. This is the final column that you add.